# Copy values from one struct to another in Golang

Tags: go, struct

I've two structs:

```
type UpdateableUser struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName string
    Email string
    Tlm float64
    Dob time.Time
}

type User struct {
    Id string
    FirstName string
    LastName string
    Email string
    DOB time.Time
    Tlm float64
    created time.Time
    updated time.Time
}
```

Through a binder I bind request data to the updateableUser struct, therefore I might have an updateableUser with only one "real" value, like uu here:

```
uu := UpdateableUser{Lastname: "Smith"}
```

Now I want to set only the not "emtpy" values from UpdateableUser to User. Can you please give me a hint or more?

Comment: You write code of the form `if field x is not empt: copy value` for each field. Don't go fancy here.

Comment: Bind directly to `User`, so any fields the client supplies will be written directly into `User`, the rest unchanged.

Comment: But than the client can supply Id or created, too. What I want to forbid through the UpdateableUser struct. And the User struct might have values already (from DB)

Comment: The binding library you use most likely has some way to mark excluded fields from the process. But we don't know anything about what you use and how you do it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend embedding the Updateable struct into the larger struct:

```
type UpdateableUser struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    Email     string
    Tlm       float64
    Dob       time.Time
}

type User struct {
    UpdateableUser
    ID      string
    created time.Time
   updated time.Time
}

func (u *User) UpdateFrom(src *UpdateableUser) {
    if src.FirstName != "" {
        u.FirstName = src.FirstName
    }
    if src.LastName != "" {
        u.LastName = src.LastName
    }
    // ... And other properties. Tedious, but simple and avoids Reflection
}
```

This allows you to use `UpdateableUser` as an interface to make it explicit which properties can be updated.

Comment: Alright, not the nicest way for long structs but as you say, avoids reflection. THX